# MVC Controller get value from Dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, controller

I have a kendo grid and I'm writing the controller logic for it.  I would like specific values to be defined by a dropdown list in my view.  How can change the values in my controller based on my dropdown list selection.

```
public ActionResult tbl_vessels_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, decimal[] param_bhp, decimal[] param_deck)
    {
        var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        var futureDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(21);

        IEnumerable<tbl_vessels> tbl_vessels = db.tbl_vessels
            .Where(c => 
                (c.vessel_type.Contains("[DROPDOWNVALUE]")) &&
                (c.fixture_stop == null) &&
                (c.vessel_status.Contains("[DROPDOWNVALUE]")) ||
                (c.vessel_type.Contains("[DROPDOWNVALUE]")) &&
                (c.spotlist_id == [DROPDOWNVALUE]) &&
                (c.fixture_start < currentDate) &&
                (c.fixture_stop < futureDate)
            );
}
```

Anywhere I want a  value from my dropdown list to appear I've marked with [DROPDOWNVALUE].  It may not be possible or it may be something that requires javascript to do but having never tried before I thought I would ask for advice.

Comment: Is the drop down list outside of the grid. i.e. is the read action/ filter based on this value before you want to return the result set. It isn't entirely clear what you are asking as you start off asking about a grid then move to a dropdown in a view. Some more context around the problem will aid in giving a better solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the read of the kendogrid you can use the data property to let the kendogrid send additional parameters with the request.
(Assuming that it's a kendogrid, but the data property will be there for most if not all requests in kendo)

```
.Read(read => read.Action("tbl_vessels_Read", "Controller")
                          .Data("additionalData"))
```

Then create a Javascript function that fills this data with the data from the drop-downs.

```
function additionalData() {
    return {
        param_bhp: varparam_bhp,
        param_deck: varparam_deck
    };
}
```

Comment: This is the approach I ended up taking and it works well.